# ASM - Concatenating pre processor labels

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm new with assembly code, so any help would be appreciated.
I'm writing macro to create function as follows:

```
.macro CREATE_FUNC ARG1 ARG2
.align 4
.func ARG1
       cmpl    $0x1, some_var
       je      skip_exec
       call ARG2
 skip_exec:
       iret
.endfunc
.endm
```

now I want to create two functions **a** and **b**, so I'm writing the following code:

```
CREATE_FUNC a, aa
CREATE_FUNC b, bb
```

However when I'm compiling the code I'm getting "symbol 'skip_exec' is already defined" error, meaning that CREATE_FUNC of **b** fails because 'skip_exec' was already defined for **a** function.
I thought to solve it by one of the following:

1. Concatenating label skip_exec to the input parameter ARG1, something like   skip_exec##ARG1 - but it didn't work and I don't know how to do that...
2. I saw it's possible to define "LOCAL skip_exec" section in the beginning of the macro. But it didn't solve the issue, I keep getting the error in the compilation.

can anyone please help me understanding how to do (1) and why (2) doesn't work to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can use local labels by putting \@ prefix:

```
.macro CREATE_FUNC ARG1 ARG2
.align 4
.func ARG1
       cmpl    $0x1, some_var
       je      skip_exec\@
       call ARG2
 skip_exec\@:
       iret
.endfunc
.endm
```

Comment: No this solution shall *not* be working. The GNU assembler maintains `\@` as the macro counter, thus in this piece of sample code you would define two symbols `skip_exec0` and `skip_exec1`, while still invoke `je skip_exec` which makes `skip_exec` here an undefined symbol.

Comment: Also, as `\@` is actually working as a counter, it helps in many cases, but not this one.

Comment: I changed to code to jump to skip_exec\@ instead of skip_exec. It's working well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [local labels](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC48L):

```
.macro CREATE_FUNC ARG1 ARG2
.align 4
.func ARG1
       cmpl    $0x1, some_var
       je      1f
       call ARG2
 1:
       iret
.endfunc
.endm
```